# Listener or callback funcion for contextual voice commands on google glass?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

Just before the contextual voice command menu appears on the screen, I would like to perform some actions. In this case, I am playing a video and I would like it to pause.  As of now, I haven't been able to find anything (documentation for this is very poor).

I was also exploring the use of public boolean onPreparePanel(int featureId, View view, Menu menu), which might not be the right thing to do, but it happens that this function is not being triggered either.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

I would put whatever function you are trying to implement in the `onCreatePanelMenu()`

Comment: That doesn't work very well. He wants to pause the video when the menu pops up, not when the activity starts.

Comment: Jessie is correct. OnCreatePanelMenu doesnt help me here. I want a function similar to onPrepareOptionsMenu, but for contextual voice commands. onPreparePanel should be the one, but the callback simply doesnt work

Comment: I've tried a few of the different callbacks, including onContextMenuPepare, onMenuOpen, and some of the others. I've yet to actually get a callback. You might want to create an issue in the GDK issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks Jessie!, I will definitely do that